# Is there any Java component that takes WSDL and produced a pretty print HTML page of its description?

Tags: java, soap, wsdl

Is there anything written in Java that displays an HTML page showcasing the methods of a SOAP API and allowing you to test the methods direct from the page?

Something like this: http://ws.cdyne.com/NotifyWS/PhoneNotify.asmx

Thanks in advance,
Kyle

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse for Java EE developers does this. Here's a tutorial http://wiki.eclipse.org/Using_Web_Service_Explorer_to_test_a_Web_service

CXF does this when generating end points too, once they're deployed.